# Better way to apply this function to each row a data frame?

Tags: r

I'd like to apply a function to each row of a data frame, as below.  I know how to use apply in the case where the data frame contains only numbers, but what if the rows contain, say, booleans / logicals, strings and integers?  Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,
                 y=c(TRUE, FALSE),
                 z=letters[1:10],
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

RowFunction <- function(row) {
  if (row$y) return(row$x)
  return (row$z)
}

sapply(1:dim(df)[1], function(i) { RowFunction(df[i, ]) })
```

Is there a better way to do this?  My first thought was to use `apply(df, 1, RowFunction)` after adding `row <- as.list(row)` to the beginning of RowFunction, but this doesn't work because apply coerces df into an array, which can't handle rows containing different data types.

Just for my R knowledge, I'd like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this than `sapply(1:dim(df)[1], ... )`.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to point out that _all_ elements in a vector will be of the same mode. The only way to get results that vary in mode or type will be to return a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, you can simply use `ifelse`:

```
sapply(1:dim(df)[1], function(i) { RowFunction(df[i, ]) })
 [1] "1" "b" "3" "d" "5" "f" "7" "h" "9" "j"

with(df, ifelse(y, x, z))
 [1] "1" "b" "3" "d" "5" "f" "7" "h" "9" "j"
```

---

For convenience and readability I also used `with` - this allows you to refer to a column just by name, without using the `$` operator.

Comment: +2 if I could for `ifelse` and `with`...2 of my favorites!

Answer (score 0):

The `ifelse` function can do it with `lapply`:

```
 lapply(df$y, ifelse, df$x, df$z)  # does return list with varying modes
```

My earlier (more clunky) version:

```
 res <- list()
 for(i in seq_along(rownames(df) ) ) { res <- c(res, df[i,1+2*!df[i,"y"] ]) }
 res
#--------
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] "d"

[[5]]
[1] 5

[[6]]
[1] "f"

[[7]]
[1] 7

[[8]]
[1] "h"

[[9]]
[1] 9

[[10]]
[1] "j"
```